# Why is stripe creating the customer twice with firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, stripe-payments

[RESOLVED] The issue is when I call the function subscribe() after le .then(() => when the account is created in firebase. I think the function is called more than one time.

I use Firebase and stripe to manage subscription payments (through the stripe subscription firebase extension) and have an issue when the user signs up and is added to stripe.

When the users signs up, an account is created in my Firebase app. Then he is redirected to a Stripe checkout session. In between he is added to the customers section of my stripe account (I don't manage that, it is done in the backend through the extension I believe).
**Issue -> the customer is created twice in Stripe.**

One of the duplicated customer in Stripe has the logs : "POST /v1/customers" and "POST /v1/checkout/session".
The other has only the log "POST /v1/customers".
They both have the same firebaseUID in the metadata section in Stripe. And only one user is created in Firebase.

This is my signUp function which is called through onclick() on a button :

```
if (agreeToTerms == true && name != '' && surname != '' && companyName != '' && companyActivity != '' ) {

    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
        return db.collection('collection-users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({
            name: name,
            surname: surname,
            email: email,
            companyName: companyName,
            companyActivity: companyActivity
        })
        
    }).then(() => {
            // User signed up, now redirected to stripe checkout session to subscribe
            subscribe();
            container_signup.querySelector(".error").innerHTML = '';
    }).catch(err => {
        container_signup.querySelector(".error").innerHTML = err.message;
    });

} else {
    container_signup.querySelector(".error").innerHTML = "Please add all the required informations."
}
```

And this is my subscribe function which is used to redirect the user to the stripe checkout session (called when the account has been created) :

```
async function subscribe() {

    const docRef = await db
      .collection('collection-users')
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .collection('checkout_sessions')
      .add({
        price: 'price_id',
        success_url: 'https://mywebsite.com',
        cancel_url: 'https://mywebsite.com',
    });
    // Wait for the CheckoutSession to get attached by the extension
    docRef.onSnapshot((snap) => {
      const { error, url } = snap.data();
      if (error) {
        // Show an error to your customer and 
        // inspect your Cloud Function logs in the Firebase console.
        alert(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
      }
      if (url) {
        // We have a Stripe Checkout URL, let's redirect.
        window.location.assign(url);
      }
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your help.

[EDIT] The firebase logs down below. What we can see is that the function .createCustomer creates the first customer while .createCheckoutSession creates not only the checkout session but also another customer (the duplicated one).

```
7:48:29.200 pm
ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createCustomer
Function execution started

7:48:29.202 pm
info    
gmp_mods ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createCustomer
⚙️ Creating customer object for [t5LdbvNH5hSOFe7ECuzpHfWke1x2].

7:48:29.215 pm
outlined_flag   
gmp_mods ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createCheckoutSession
Function execution started

7:48:29.218 pm
info    
gmp_mods ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createCheckoutSession
 ⚙️ Creating checkout session for doc [UkCpB5Yqw8c9RR76wyp6].

7:48:29.464 pm
info    
gmp_mods ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createCheckoutSession
⚙️ Creating customer object for [t5LdbvNH5hSOFe7ECuzpHfWke1x2].

7:48:29.636 pm
info    
gmp_mods ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createCustomer
✅Created a new customer: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/customers/cus_KMlAFc3l3oAgnd.

7:48:29.637 pm
outlined_flag   
gmp_mods ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createCustomer
Function execution took 437 ms, finished with status: 'ok'

7:48:29.925 pm
info    
gmp_mods ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createCheckoutSession
✅Created a new customer: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/customers/cus_KMlAUuGRyge978.

7:48:30.679 pm
info    
gmp_mods ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createCheckoutSession
✅Checkout session created for doc [UkCpB5Yqw8c9RR76wyp6].

7:48:30.679 pm
outlined_flag   
gmp_mods ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createCheckoutSession
 Function execution took 1464 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the functions logs for `createCustomer`?

Comment: No there is no error messages in the functions logs in Firebase. But what I see is that one logs says that the function .createCustomer created the first customer while the second duplicated one is created through the function .createCheckoutSession. I don't understand why. (I edited the post with the logs)

Comment: I'm guessing your call to `db.collection('collection-users').doc(cred.user.uid).set()` overwrites the `stripeId` that gets set during customer creation, so when you make the call to `subscribe()` it can't find the Stripe customer ID. Try changing your code to `db.collection('collection-users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({ ... }, { merge: true })` so that your call merges data with the existing record.